# Error while using IJulia

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia

I have installed Ipython and IJulia as mentioned in the github repo https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl

But when I run "1+2" in the notebook I get the below error

> Kernel Restarting. The kernel appears to have died. It will restart
>   automatically.

Not able to figure out the issue here.

Comment: Please look at GitHub issues for the project and see if any of them helps resolve. If they don't then open a new GitHub issue.

Comment: Issue is same as https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl/issues/74. This issue is also being discussed in julia-users group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/julia-users/-4gekWLVBdI/OeN62NrxdZIJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved now.

From Julia-users group

> Please do Pkg.update(). This is due to a bug in Nettle.jl on x86, fixed here:
>
> https://github.com/staticfloat/Nettle.jl/commit/1f926498ca35898d4e7d2eb336b602a204abf299